# Get youtube video url wrong using java

Tags: java, video, youtube

I use java to get youtube video url from a youtube url,it seems like i should decode video url twice to get the original video url,but something is wrong when i access the video url which i get from my code. Im sure i can access any video url which i get when i first run the code after i finish the code, but after that ,i can not access any video url i get no matter the video url is from decode first or twice. I suppose maybe only youtube itself can access the video url i get or the server blocked my IP. So i need you guys to help me to tell me whats wrong and how i could do to get the video url that can play, thx. My code and answer is below:

```
        try {
        String ytUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cj3AV92fJ90";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(ytUrl);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        String html = "";
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line.replace("\\u0026", "&"));
        }
        in.close();
        html = str.toString();

        String val=RegexUtil.find(html,"stream_map\":.*?\"(.*?)\"",1);

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(val)) {
            String url = URLDecoder.decode(val, "UTF-8");

            System.out.println("1 decode url: "+url);
            url = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");;
            System.out.println("2 decode url: "+url );
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> 1 decode url: url=https://r4---sn-i3b7knlk.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=o-AE4MBDOnLdC4X0a7wjJ63diBNkBpJ2XiuejUOXrB8onv&dur=421.442&mime=video%2Fmp4&fvip=4&requiressl=yes&ms=au%2Conr&mt=1540798558&ratebypass=yes&itag=22&pl=25&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&source=youtube&mv=m&mn=sn-i3b7knlk%2Csn-npoeene7&lmt=1537570091802082&key=yt6&ei=8LjWW9P1Ns2R8gOGhKO4AQ&c=WEB&expire=1540820305&ip=114.113.240.105&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=362500&mm=31%2C26&itag=22&type=video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2"&s=C8C80C74C92B4306498EE1183D683A0E60962F69BD.4F1AE9CE009B83425F389362CFC2FE23A45948D5&quality=hd720&sp=signature

2 decode url: url=https://r4---sn-i3b7knlk.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=o-AE4MBDOnLdC4X0a7wjJ63diBNkBpJ2XiuejUOXrB8onv&dur=421.442&mime=video/mp4&fvip=4&requiressl=yes&ms=au,onr&mt=1540798558&ratebypass=yes&itag=22&pl=25&sparams=dur,ei,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,expire&source=youtube&mv=m&mn=sn-i3b7knlk,sn-npoeene7&lmt=1537570091802082&key=yt6&ei=8LjWW9P1Ns2R8gOGhKO4AQ&c=WEB&expire=1540820305&ip=114.113.240.105&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=362500&mm=31,26&itag=22&type=video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2"&s=C8C80C74C92B4306498EE1183D683A0E60962F69BD.4F1AE9CE009B83425F389362CFC2FE23A45948D5&quality=hd720&sp=signature